# Facebook Callback JSON does not return email sometimes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Graph API.

I am requesting email permission and it works all fine except for some users, the json does not return email field. I am not sure why this happens. The code is same and it works great for all users, returns email field except 1 in 100 or so users where it does not have this field in json. All other fields are there.

Has anyone faced this problem before ??

I checked the facebook privacy settings and there is nothing that prevents email from coming in json if user grants email access to facebook app, yet this is happening to me. I searched the net and no one else seems to be facing this issue.

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: It depends on the users on Facebook. They can set a privacy policy to never share email addresses.

Comment: Thanks for reply. where is such an option that prevents email from coming in json even after user grants email access to app while doing FB Connect.

Comment: I think it's on the user privacy tab. You can setup what an application can or cannot see.

Comment: I tried all possible combination of privacy settings but could not reproduce the issue. I even set email address visiblitilty to 'Only Me' remove the app and tried doing FB connect again. Then it shows pop up asking email access to user and everything works fine. Just dont know exactly what setting is causing this

Comment: @zing did you manage to find a solution to this issue? I seem to be experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I've had a similar problem, I've also found that if I take the same exact key and run it again it comes back with the email address. It seems like every so often they just leave it out for the hell of it.

Comment: This happens to me about 20-30% of the time. I just ask for the email in a separate activity or view in case the JSON does not return the email.

Answer (score 2):

Never makes assumptions about what Facebook will send you, never expect every field to be present and never expect a Graph request to do what you want.

Facebook sometimes do things like this, a missing field here and there, a cryptic and unexpected error somewhere else… While it can be no harm be aware that it also happens in critial places like in the signed_request sent when an user launches an app.

You also have to know that 'your' Facebook may not be everyone else's Facebook. They do geographic and somewhat random deployments of their code. An option to hide your e-mail address to every application could appear for someone but not for someone else, without any particular reason.

Considering your particular issue, I doubt there is an option to hide you e-mail address to an app who has the mail permission, but if the permission is not mandatory someone could accept your app and cherry-pick optional permissions later.

Answer (score 0):

I dealing with this issue recently. Apparently, facebook only promise to return "valid email" address. Some account do not having any "valid email". They can be account who using phone for validation, or account that email is expired. I tried with a account which email, lets said "xxxx.gmail.com" is expired, when query that account graph, i unable to get any email shows(by using facebook debugger). However, when i login xxxx.gmail.com in gmail, and re-activate the email, and i query graph api again for the account, it able to return me email.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue for a while, which caused some heavy head banging against the wall.

in my case the issue was due to the fact that some users have **unverified emails** or **no email at all** (when signing up via mobile/SMS).
in this case facebook will not provide an email on the response.

from the [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/):

> note: this field will not be returned if no valid email address is
>   available for the user

sources:

1. https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/61
2. [Register with Facebook sometimes doesn't provide email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email) (sebastian's and colm's answers)
3. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that worked for me was requesting for permitted fields through the API:

```
FB.api("/me", {fields: "email,..."}, callback)
```

This totally fixed the issue.
Hope that helps.