# Facebook Graph not returning email

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**UPDATE** It seems that my personnal email address had not been used for years. Facebook marked it as inactive and did not return it as part of the JSON.

I am authenticating a user with Facebook on the client side using this url :

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
  client_id=xxx&
  redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&
  scope=email
```

I receive a code I then exchange for a token :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
  code=xxx&
  client_id=xxx&
  client_secret=xxx&
  redirect_uri=xxx
```

I then send the token to my server and I fetch the Fb Graph in order to get some user info, including the email.

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx
```

For some reason, I get all the user 'about' info, but **not his/her email**!

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email

Comment: I tested with my own facebook account and the address I signed up with has not been used in years! It may very well be the cause.

Comment: If you use version 2.4, then you must request the email in the fields=... variable (and any other public profile fields). Otherwise /me would give you just the name and id

Comment: @PalDev, wish i had found your answer before i wasted half a day to work it out myself in 2020. Facebook docs still dodgy, they still have not updated to say this is the case in 2020 (or 2015 as per your answer !)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4):

> By default, not all the fields in a node or edge are returned when you
>   make a query. You can choose the fields (or edges) you want returned
>   with the "fields" query parameter. This is really useful for making
>   your API calls more efficient and fast.

This is valid from v2.4, (previous versions retrieved some default fields).

When you register a new app you are entitled automatically (without manual review) to three permissions: email, public_profile and user_friends. In your code "email" is in scope (which is good) so just change your query to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx&fields=email
```

You probably wanted the public_profile fields that you automatically got in previous versions of the API. Do so so, add "public_profile" to your scope:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
  client_id=xxx&
  redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&
  scope=email,public_profile
```

And now add the user name fields to your query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx&fields=first_name,last_name,gender,email,timezone,age_range,verified
```

Good luck

Comment: I also used to get the name as one lot which was making it difficult to identify the first and last name for international names with multiple spaces. I followed your method to get separate first and last names and thought of sharing it in case it helps someone. **/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name**

Comment: All the /me (public_profile) references can be found here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile