# facebook api explorer do not retrive email address

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement signin/-up via facebook, but do not receive email address on request. Sure, I've grabbed the email permission before, but no success.
So I tried with FB Graph API Explorer and again my private account. Yes, access token with email permission, but no email will be delivered, instead "Field is empty or disallowed by the access token". 
Access token? Just created, with email permission. 
Empty? How could it be, when it is required on signup?

Using a different account of a friend, worked like a charm. Could it depend on my account settings?

Answer (score 0):

Even if the permissions are given, a user can turn Platform off in the Apps Settings. Check the settings and permissions your App is showing, here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=opt_out&view

If its alright, you can follow this discussion: [Register with Facebook sometimes doesn't provide email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer. I spent a lot of time to figure out what is going on. It seems, that my email address caused the problem, which is facebook@mydomain.com. After changing to a different one, without facebook in it, I get response as expected.