# Using facebook connect is it possible for a user not to have an email address?

Tags: facebook

I just saw an exception in my application I have never seen before, someone tried registering using facebook and the application tried to insert a `null` value into the email field. Of course there might be something wrong on my end but just thought I would check first whether this it's possible for a facebook user not to have an email address?

Yes my application makes a request to facebook with `scope: email` and people have registered before with no problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible. You could find many questions on SO regarding the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. I suppose extra logic will have to be added to prompt a facebook connect user to enter their email address if they have none with facebook.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for a facebook user not to have email. 
This could happen when the email with which the user has created his facebook account expired. It happened to me once.