# Email address is not getting fetched on Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook PHP SDK for making the user login into our Application. Along with basic details i have asked for extended permissions like email, location, work history etc..
For most of the users, its working fine(i am able to get everything i am asking for). But for few users i am unable to fetch email id from facebook.

My login url is generated using following code

```
$data['fb_url'] = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email, user_birthday, user_work_history'));
```

I tried to reproduce the same thing but setting my email to private(Only Me) mode but still i can fetch my email id since i am explicitly asking in extended permissions.

I am at my wits end to understand or reproduce this error for my profile. But still for some users this problem does occur. And there is no way i can see their facebook profile. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not every user has an email address set in their profile – Facebook also allows people to sign up using their mobile number.

Comment: This has been asked and answered thousands a time! Please do a search before posting a ques next time. Good luck

Comment: @Shadowfax maybe u haven’t read the question properly.. I didn’t ask how to fetch email. What I mentioned is a singular situation which happens with 1 between 100 users..Never mind, i figured out the reason

Comment: Well, I read the ques properly and it has been asked several times. Just like one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email

Comment: @Shadowfax Sorry, I take my words back..I missed it. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause for this problem.
This problem occurs for users who have not set their Primary Email Address (They have many email address but they haven’t pointed out which is their primary email address) under General Account setting tab.

I tried using such accounts on various famous sites which has Facebook login & even they couldn’t retrieve the email address from such accounts.

So, its not the problem with my code. We just have to handle such scenarios & let users know that we didn’t receive their email address.

Thanks