# Facebook login:

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement the login with facebook in Web application. Basically, I use the SDK for Javascript and, during the first authentication, I ask the permission for the basic user details, email and user location. I tried my code with several accounts without any problem, but with one account I can't get the email address and I don't know why.

E.g. using the following small piece of code:

```
function fb_login(){
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      print_me();
    }
  },{ scope: 'email,user_location' });
}

function print_me () {
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Facebook asks the user for the permission and it correctly states the information I need. Then  print_me prints all the profile but, with that particular user, the email field is missing (but I still get the location). If I debug the token with the Access Token Debugger I receive the confirmation that the scope of the token is: email, user_friends, user_location.

The privacy settings of this user are the same of other users I receive the email.

Processing the token server-side with facebook-sdk (Python) gives me the same result: full profile but not the email address. Any clue about what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: check the privacy of the user in more dept, you are obviously missing somethign

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you pull some random number of profiles, say 100, you will find that there are about 75 different combinations of data.  Some will have a "job history" and others will not, for example.  If the profile is old enough, then the profile may have missing info.  Try using the Graph API explorer and also check to make sure that your URL is in the "app setttings".  Facebook will only allow info to be accessed by a site/app that is properly configured in the settings.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried with Graph Explorer but I had the same issue. At the end I discovered that the holder of that particular account I was trying to access simply hasn't confirmed the email address and the FB api doesn't return the email address if it is not confirmed, as I discovered here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email)

Comment: Yeah, you can get back anywhere from five to twenty-five elements in the array.