# Facebook login not work for everyone app approved by client

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I get a headache from this.

I tested many times with different Facebook accounts from family members.
Most from Netherlands , a few from Germany and one from USA and Italy.

Now i have a friend from Latvia who is unable to Register/Login.My session responds he not provide his email address.

I did a check over Teamviewer, removed my account from the website and logged in on Facebook on his PC.
I went on his PC's browser to my site and the Registration and Login worked?
I'm stunned , the app is granted permission on my friends FB settings.

What could be wrong?

Message to the moderators:::::::: This question can be flagged as duplicate or whatever flag you have for it.The same issue is asked/discussed here: [Register with Facebook sometimes doesn't provide email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email) ..Sorry to give you work.

Comment: I am sort of confused, so it did not worked, when your friend was logging, but you got him logged in successfuly through Teamviewer?

Comment: No ,over teamviewer i logged to facebook with my account.I tested the registration/login procedure on HIS browser/pc true Teamviewer.

Comment: It took me a while to find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email i think we have the problem here found.