# get email from android facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, email, facebook-android-sdk

i have working code to get user info except the email. this is my request code:

```
private void requestLoginFb() {  
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();  
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(
                Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email")).setCallback(
                fbCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(act, true, fbCallback);
    }
}
```

here where i get user info

```
Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
    new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        if (null != user) {
            C.trace("user name: " + user.getName());
            C.trace("user gender: " + user.asMap().get("gender"));
        }
    }
});
```

my graph result no email:

```
GraphObject{graphObjectClass=Map, state={"id":"10000xxxxxxx","first_name":"xxxx","username":"xxxxxx","timezone":x,"locale":"en_US","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/xxxxxx","name":"xxxxx","last_name":"xxxxx","gender":"male","education":[{"type":"xxxx","school":{"id":"xxxxx","name":"xxxxx"}}],"updated_time":"xxxxxxx"}}
```

i'm concern about the way i put permission. then i put basic info and email on session. and i don't know if this the right way.

**UPDATE**

here screenshot while request to facebook. even there is a friend list that i don't put on permission. and on my graph, still no email there.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've added the permissions after being authorized once. So check out what all permissions you've provided to this app [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) by clicking on the *Edit*.

If you find that `email` permission is not set, then you can logout of the app/remove the app from the settings and then login again; so that you can be authorized again with the `email` permission included.

Comment: i put permission while i start asking request to facebook. can you give me sample where i must put permission. btw, i have update my question with image.  and from my facebook app, it written "this app needs: your basic info, your email address" so i think my permission is working well, but facebook didn't give me the email on the graph

Comment: Can you see the email permission in the link I've mentioned in the answer?

Comment: yes i see that, i found my app need basic info and email address.

Comment: Make request to `/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email` and see what's the response

Comment: If your code is correct, then only this could be the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18377407/1343690. Try it with another user and let me kno the results

Comment: great. thanks a lot. i always used fake facebook id for debuging and also with valid yahoo email (i think). i dont know why facebook think my 'fake' email is invalid. but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is well known issue ..... for some accounts facebook don't wanna return email even when the code is correct. could you please try with other accounts?

Answer (score 0):

For getting email from facebook, try it something like below.

```
String email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
Textview mEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
mEmail.setText(email);
```

By using this above code i am successfully able to get the email of facebbok user. Try it and let me know if you still face any problem.

Comment: the problem is not about the email parameter, but there is no email on my graph. please check my graph result.