# Its possible to not obtain the users email in Facebook Login?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im with a problem using the Facebook PHP SDK to implement Facebook Login on a Site.

I use an email to identify the users of my app. SO, when a new user logins with Facebook I search if his mail is in the database, if not i create a new user.

The problem is that a small number of users (2 specifically) have problems with the login system. When i checked the database (in the "users" table), i noticed that they have accounts created, but **wihouth the email**.

The question is: **Is possible to not have access to an email of a facebook user** if he gave the permissions to the app?

If this is true, exist some kind of solution to use Facebook Login in a system that stores the user with this table?:

```
email | password | name
```

Thanks. Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that you'll not receive the email of a facebook user inspite of the fact that he gave the required permission to the app.

But chances are very minute (as you've mentioned too- *a small number of users (2 specifically) have problems with the login system*)

The **reason** for that? Follow this discussion- [Register with Facebook sometimes doesn't provide email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email/18377407#18377407)

**Solution**?

It depends why exactly you need an email. If its just an identifier for a user, you can save the `username` or `id` of the user (yes those are unique). Yet, this will just be an identifier- but since for the cases you are not getting email, you cant do anything else about that, right?