# How to obtain internal facebook email

Tags: facebook

We have an option to signUp/signIn users via facebook, using their email as unique ID. [We encountered a problem with "email" field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email), and trying to find a solution to being able to register user with meaningfull email anyway, and login him via same account later. Is facebook internal email is an option here? How to obtain it?

Answer (score 0):

No, the 'email' field on the '/user' object is the only email address you can get from the API/Facebook.

I would advise to catch any missing email fields during registration and if that happens shows your own form/dialog to let the user enter it manually.

Comment: Yet the second time he will try to login via facebook button he will have no email, and will not login properly.

Comment: You can store the User ID you retrieve from the login together with the email field.

Comment: the (app scoped) user id is unique already, you don´t need the email for that