# Will facebook public profile always contains email Id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating a facebook login functionality for my website. 
When user login through facebook , then I want to fetch emailId ( which can come with public profile ).

Is it possible ( in any case ) that when I fetch public profile then it does not contain users email Id ?

Thanks
Amit Aggarwal

Comment: The public profile does not contain email by default: http://graph.facebook.com/4. Alsoyou can just not show it in your front-end, but nothing's wrong with in being included in the response.

Comment: @dragonjet : Ok If i ask for email Id also in scope , then is it possible that I donot receive it in response ?

Comment: you can specify the fields you want by adding `?fields=` to your request, like in the earlier example, you only want the first name: http://graph.facebook.com/4?fields=first_name check your specific SDK on how to pass this fields parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very less chances that you'll get `email` without asking for its permission as a public info.

You gotta ask for permission `email` to get one. But still there could be chances (3-4 in 100) that you'll not get email even when user gave you the permission and you can do nothing about that. You can check out this discussion for the reasons: [Register with Facebook sometimes doesn't provide email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email/18377407#18377407)

Comment: Yes , thats I want to know . @Sahil , can you tell me when/why there are 3-4 such chances are there ? because if any such user try to register on my website whose emailId can not be fetch , I could suggest him some solution.

Comment: For "Why", checkout the discussion I've mentioned in the answer. If you just want an id for a user, use "facebookid" else explicitly ask from your user to enter the email.

Comment: Thanks I got it .. I checked out discussion also.