# Unable to perform user registration with Facebook using allauth and django-rest-auth. getting incorrect value error

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth, dj-rest-auth

I am trying to implement social authentication, I am using django-allauth, django-rest-auth for this.
my views

```py
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import FacebookOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client

class FacebookLoginView(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter
    client_class = OAuth2Client
```

on making post request in the above view with `access_token` it returns the error

```
{"non_field_errors":["Incorrect value"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: Most of cases issues should be coming from using a wrong APP ID. Make sure the access_token belong to you app

Comment: I am trying to perform facebook login not with google.

Comment: Then probably a wrong APP ID is used, make sure that the access_token belong to your app

Comment: oh you are right, my Id was wrong. but I have one issue now, I am not getting email for a facebook user

Comment: In settings.py set configuration ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED to True

Comment: its already set

Comment: Any error message ?

Comment: I am getting this in my `Graph API explorer` "The email address field was not returned. This may be because the email address was missing or invalid or hasn't been confirmed."
for my account.

Comment: Please check this thread, it might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email