# Graph API does not return email for some users

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We are experiencing issue with missing emails in users profile fetched with FB Graph API. All those profiles belongs to already registered users that had the email in the profile. This is definitely not issue registering users without email or with unverified email.

I know that FB returns only verified email, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571410/facebook-callback-json-does-not-return-email-sometimes) but it started suddenly for approx 10% of registered users. The reason is not missing email in the user's profile since we don't allow to use Facebook sign up without email. We used API without version so we tired to set API version to original URL `"https://graph.facebook.com/v0.0/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large),email` as someone suggests and also tried debug request: `"https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=$accessToken&debug=all`. Everything is ok.

What could be wrong? Is it FB bug?

Comment: Facebook allows accounts to be created via phone number instead of email. 10% sounds about right to me.

Comment: I edited the post and emphasized that missing email in the profile is not the issue. I tried many ways to edit my profile and couldn't find any way to remove the email. And even if it could be possible it does not explain why it happened suddenly, approx 1000 invalid requests per day.

Comment: Take a peek at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data/ and the "Data Access Expiration" section.